# Why is my typo3 based root/home pagetitle inheriting to sub-page titles?

Tags: typo3

I have the pagetitle attribute set in my root page of my typo3 site.  For some reason, that title seems to inherit to sub-pages even when I explicitly have the pagetitle set in the sub-page.  For example, say I have my root/home page pagetitle set to "HOMEPAGE" and I have a sub-page pagetitle set to "SUBPAGE".  The pagetitle that will appear on the sub-page when it is rendered is:  "SUBPAGE - HOMEPAGE".  Why is this happening?  How do I set the page title to the value I want without it inheriting values from the root?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter this behaviour in Typoscript:

```
config.noPageTitle = 2
## value 2 is correct
## see: http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=1382
page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.field = subtitle // title
page.headerData.10.wrap = <title>| &nbsp; - deinedomain.com</title>
```

Comment: Stupid question here, but does this go in to the setup of the root/homepage or in to the sub-page that would inherit the title?

Comment: In the Typoscript template of your root page. Templates in TYPO3 are always passed on to the children